# No active contexts for scope in EJB service

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, cdi, seam3

I have EJB bean and there is a class RemoveInactiveUsersTask extends TimerTask when I invoke method which update user status in DB.

This is sample code of my class:

```
@Singleton
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class UsersStatusManager implements Serializable {

@SuppressWarnings("CdiInjectionPointsInspection")
    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

...


}
```

And this is my errors:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-2" javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

I use JSF with CDI and Seam 3.
Method is of course annotate with @Transactional and everything is ok until I use it in timer. 
I tried to use unmanaged EntityManager but then I have transaction required exceptions.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: So what does the `RemoveInactiveUsersTask` class look like? I suspect you have a request scope on one of your EJB's - if you do and you try to run it in a separate thread - it won't work, as there is no request context available there.

Answer (score 4):

The exception is correct, there is no active request context here.  You should try a lower scope; e.g. dependent.